# key error when writing out dictionary to file

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary in python called `shared_double_lists` with 6 keys `[(0, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (0, 3), (0, 2)]`.

I am trying to output the values of key `(0, 1)` to a text file, and am using this code:

```
output = open('test_output.txt', 'w')
counter = 0
for value in shared_double_lists['(0, 1)']:
    output.write(shared_double_lists['(0, 1)'][counter])
    output.write ("\t")
    output.write ("\n")
    counter +=1
output.close()
```

However, I keep on receiving this key error: `KeyError: '(0, 1)'`

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong, and how I can get the values for each key of my dictionary to be output to a text file?

code I used to make dictionary:

```
shared_double_lists = {}    
for line in allLinesList:
    species = set(range(len(line))) 
    for i, j in combinations(range(len(line)), 2): 
        remaining = species - {i, j} 
        if line[i][4] != "." and line[i][4] == line[j][4] and all(line[i][4] != line[x][4] for x in remaining): 
            shared_double_lists.setdefault((i, j), []).append(line[j])
```

Comment: Make your example self-contained, so that we can paste it into https://repl.it for testing.

Comment: Add your array definition, in other words.

Comment: It looks like the keys are tuples and not strings? See comment #1.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp This is very likely to be the case. How can I convert the tuples into strings?

Comment: Your addition isn't great cause `allLinesList` and `combinations` aren't defined. Anyway, how you create `shared_double_lists` isn't important - just post its value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keys of `shared_double_lists` are tuples, not strings. Simply remove the quote marks.

```
shared_double_lists[(0, 1)]
```

Comment: I have tried that, but now I get this error for the next line:   `output.write(shared_double_lists[(0, 1)][counter])
TypeError: expected a character buffer object`

Comment: @wilberox OK, great! That means we fixed the bug you asked about and now you've found a different bug. Please ask a new question, and please include a [mre].